# Receive JSON format through REST api without using REST Client

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

IN magento, as I am using REST api to get the product details with url like http://myserver.com/magento/api/rest/products? But this url returns only in XML format. But I need it in the JSON format.

Can anyone suggest me how to get it in JSON format without using REST client??

Answer (score 3):

you need to [set request header explicitly to application/json](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/response_formats.html) then the response is served in json.